# CRUD API React - method not allowed 405

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have set up a project with DRF + Postgre for the backend and React-admin for the frontend.

```
class CreateTracker(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
""" This endpoint allows for creation of a tracker """
    queryset = Tracker.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TrackerSerializer
```

This is the view for my create object, I can create and get a status 201.
But when I try to create an object from React-Admin.

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/trackers/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

That is what I get in the network tab. I have noticed that the URL is missing "create" after the last slash and I think that that is the problem, but do not know how to solve it.

```
path('trackers/create/', CreateTracker.as_view(), name="create_tracker")
```

That is the urlpattern for the create method.

Can someone help?

Comment: It seems to be hitting another view. In order for it to use `CreateTracker`, you need to use the url `trackers/create/` and not `api/trackers/`

Comment: I cannot do it like that. Everything is connected with the drf dataProvider, the link is 127.0.0.1:8000/api and the resources get name "tracker" which appends " /trackers" after the api

Comment: Can you share all your url config? Does `create_tracker` resolve to `trackers/create/` or `api/trackers/create/`?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/#/api/trackers/create this is the url from react, and it is correct, but when I try to create an item from it, it gives me 405 method not allowed. http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/trackers/create is the django url that gives 201 created and there is something that is happening under the hood.

Comment: But the error says it tried to POST/create on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/trackers/`..

Comment: `Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/trackers/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed`

Comment: path('api/', include("location_api.urls")),  ---- main url

path('trackers/create/', CreateTracker.as_view(), name="create_tracker"),    --- secondary url

export const dataProvider = drfProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api');   --- data provider for react

<Resource name="trackers" -- resource that gives the react url aswell

Comment: Hmm not sure about the react side, but the error is clear. Backend received the POST request on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/trackers/` which it doesn't support hence the 405

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I do not know why it does not read the url correctly. How could I set it up so that it will get the response from 127.0.0.1:8000/api/trackers/create ?

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about react. Perhaps create a separate question for that and tag it with react?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to use Django-rest and React-admin, I have found a solution to the problem:

- The react server is waiting for a PUT method, while the ListCreateAPIView sends a POST method and the error comes from that end.
- In order to create a full simple CRUD, I used ModelViewSet and created a single class with it, which allowed me to list, create, update and delete, all from a single line of code in the urlpatterns and a single class in the views.

Hope that this helps anyone who encounters this problem.